# Код не выдает ошибок, но работает неправильно

Tags: python

Это мой код:

```
print('Test Program')
print("This is my proga!")
name = input("Ваше имя: ")

print(name, ", добро пожаловать в темный мир.")

answer = 'End'
while answer != 'End':
   answer = input("Ты бы хотел взять какое-нибудь оружие? (Y/N/End): ")
   if answer1 == "Y":
       print("1-Пулемёт")
       print("2-Гранатомет")
       print("3-Однозарядный пистолет")
       print("4-АА-12")
       answer2 = input("Ваш ответ:")
   if answer2 == '1' or answer2 == '2':
       print("Хороший выбор.")
   elif answer2 == '3':
       print("Плохой выбор, возьми другое.")
   else:
       print("Великолепный выбор.")
   if answer == 'N':
       print("Ты пацифист? Круто!")
   else:
       print("Ладно, подумай ещё.")
```

но он работает не так, как хотелось бы мне. Дело в том, что после ввода имени, код сразу заканчивает работу, как будто это и есть всё написанное. Я же хочу сделать так: при нажимании Y или N, код будет работать нормально, то есть нажал Y или N, выбрал ответ и всё. А при нажимании "End" была бы надпись "Ладно, подумай ещё" и программа бы началась с вопроса "Ты бы хотел взять какое-нибудь оружие?". Так можно сделать?

Comment: а какое значение будет иметь `answer` при первой проверки условия?

Answer (score 0):

Обратите внимание:

```
answer = 'End'
while answer != 'End':
```

Условие цикла изначально не выполняется (т.к. `answer == 'End'`, то условие `answer != 'End'` ложно), поэтому вход в цикл не происходит.

Чтобы вход в цикл происходил, нужно начальное значение `answer` поменять на любое другое.

Comment: Вставил вместо моего варианта твой вариант, ну который while 'End' != 'End':. Ничего не изменилось.

Comment: тогда, выход один, завязывать с програмированием

Comment: @Mih666, я немного расширил объяснение в ответе. Надеюсь, теперь стало понятнее.

Answer (score 0):

```
print('Test Program')
print("This is my proga!")
name = input("Ваше имя: ")

print(name, ", добро пожаловать в темный мир.")

answer = ''
while answer != 'End':
   answer = input("Ты бы хотел взять какое-нибудь оружие? (Y/N/End): ")
   if answer == "Y":
       print("1-Пулемёт")
       print("2-Гранатомет")
       print("3-Однозарядный пистолет")
       print("4-АА-12")
       answer1 = input("Ваш ответ:")
       if answer1 == '1' :
          print('Well done')
       if answer1 == '2':
         print('Not bad')
       else:
         print('You will dead')
   if answer =='N':
      print('Ты пацифист?')
   if answer == 'End':
      print('Think again')
```

Просмотрите answer. Не заходил в while